# What's the best gem to integrate Backbone.js with the Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js

There are at least three well-known backbone-related gems on github:

- https://github.com/meleyal/backbone-on-rails
- https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails
- https://github.com/aflatter/backbone-rails

Which is the best one?